# django form methods are for validation only or not?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

While I am studying the new django docs on class-based views, I notice [this example code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev//topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#basic-forms):

```
# forms.py
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    def send_email(self):
        # send email using the self.cleaned_data dictionary
        pass
```

The fact of seeing `send_email` as a method of `ContactForm` really annoys me. I have always thought form methods should be for validation purpose and methods that consume forms (like `send_email` in this case) should be in *the views layer*. Am I missing anything here? Or should the example be corrected?

Comment: Then are you opposed to a modelforms `save()` method? If some functionality is specific to a form, put it on the form. If it's generic and applicable to more than the form, put it somewhere else.

Comment: @YujiTomita - "If it's generic and applicable to more than the form, put it somewhere else." I like what you said. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time I got the same weird feeling was when I encountered the `LoginForm` from `django.contrib.auth` that also verifies that the user's browser is [capable of working with cookies](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L126) aside from managing the credentials passed in.

Personally, I agree with you. I'm more inclined to think that the view should be the responsible actor for performing the action of sending the email rather than the form and that  `send_email` should be a method defined in the view.

But, then again, you can easily observe how a lot of us use Django differently or have a different approach to solving the same problems. Due to the fact that we have different concerns in mind when developing our applications, it's quite possible we have a different understanding of how certain framework components are meant to be used, which is a bit of a moot point. In the end, what's important to acknowledge is that it's possible to delegate some of the heavy-lifting from the view to the form in  a manner that's well-defined.

Comment: Filip - Glad to learn that I am not alone having this weird feeling. Yes, I agree with you that having different concerns in mind lead to different ways of developing/coding the same app/code. For me, I try to aim for consistency across my code for the same app but then that might be a the expense of flexibility and re-usability. I think your last sentence has outlined a smarter approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There is no correct answer for this one. It really depends on your coding style. Using a form for more than just validation is as valid as doing this method in the view.

The above example has some kind of advantage though. Lets say you have one model and you want to use different forms (with different logic) for it. Instead of putting the logic in the view and check which form is now used it probably better to put this logic on the form level.

Comment: Yes, I think you have got a valid point there. I guess it really depends on the situation you are dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the example. For any but the simplest of cases, your form will contain only cleaning methods; most forms do extra validation and other actions. In the end, it is just a Python class and you can do whatever you would like in it; there is no "rule" except maybe DRY.

We have form methods that validate against external services, call other procedures and trigger workflows. For such complicated logic, it is best to embed it in to the form class as it increases reusability of the code. Developers working on the view simply use the form class as a library and don't have to worry about exotic validation requirements. In this case, it actually promotes DRY.

When we have to update the logic we only update the form class's "private" methods (those prefixed with `_`). This keeps the "public" interface (documented by django) intact and all view code using that form doesn't have to be updated.